# RabbitMQ - design re-try mechanism

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core, rabbitmq

Whenever I'm not able to process events/messages that are in RabbitMQ, I am storing into MongoDB for automated and/or manual re-try. Question is how to enable automated re-try mechanism from MongoDB. How effectively can I listen to MongoDB? Is it good to store failed events/messages in MongoDB upfront? Or should I create error queue where I can listen to failed events/messages push the messages to MongoDB for manual re-try whenever automated re-try fails? Any other suggestions?

My intention is to design effective re-try mechanism for failed RabbitMQ events/messages

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical use case for [`dead-letter exchanges`](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html).

Any queue can be associated with a dead-letter exchange. A consumer which is unable to process a message for whatever reason it can reject the given message. The message will be routed to the dead-letter exchange which works as a regular one. You can therefore apply any routing policy on the dead-lettered message.